# Modifying last insertion to std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary

In the following example, I try to insert an element to `std::map` and get an iterator to the last inserted element but however I cannot modify it.

```
#include <map>

struct X {
    int x;
};

struct Y {
    int y;
};

int main()
{
    X x = {1};
    Y y = {2};

    std::map <X, Y> Z;
    std::pair<std::map<X, Y>::iterator,bool> lastval = Z.insert(std::pair<X, Y>(x, y));

    // Error: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue;
    lastval.first->first.x = 0;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys in a `std::map` (and elements of a `std::set`) are immutable - you cannot change them, as that could alter the ordering and break the map. The value of type of `std:map<K, V>` is actually `std::pair<const K, V>`. So in your case, `lastval.first->second` can be changed, but `lastval.first->first` is read-only, as it's `const`.